# libvirtd (KVM) doesn't reload the kernel when I reboot the machine

Tags: kvm, libvirt

I'm using `Direct kernel boot` with libvirtd and KVM as backend.

[image]

But, every time I recompiled the kernel, and reboot inside the VM, the changes doesn't reflect until I do a `Force off` and `Power on` again.

I'm wondering, if there's any way to change that behavior? I want the new kernel loaded every time I reboot inside the VM.